# Phase lower than -180 when reaching unity gain, is it unstable or can we substract 360?

Tags: stability, bode-plot, phase-margin

I am getting a phase of -434 degrees when reaching unity gain (0 dB point). The phase curve starts at 0 degrees, thus, can we consider that -434= -434+360= -74 degrees and the phase margin is of 180-74=106 degrees?
Or would the system be considered unstable in this case?

Best

Comment: If the curve started at 0 deg and reached -434, wouldn't it have crossed -180 and -360 while the gain was still above one? At that point you already have a negative gain margin. System may be unstable. Please add a bode plot of the open loop system

Comment: Yeah you're right phase crossover occurs while system still has high gain, it's unstable. Thus, might it be stable in the desired range of operation meaning it can operate with a phase between -360 and -434 in the desired frequency range no?

Comment: AFIAK, you can't decide to operate a device in some frequency range while it is unstable/oscillating at another frequency. It is not practical. If it is unstable, you have to stabilize it.

Comment: First off, the only point to consider for the phase margin measurement is when the loop gain magnitude is 0 dB or 1. If you have negative phase margin or an argument beyond -360° at 0 dB, then you have a problem. If the phase goes beyond -360° before the magnitude drops to 1, it can be conditionally stable. Second, how do you measure the loop gain? This is important to verify whether your limit is 180° or 360° (0°). Posting a sketch of your setup would be relevant.